# How to initialize a webcomponent (remove and then render) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, web-component, event-listener, custom-element, queryselector

How to initialize a `webcomponent` (remove and then render) in Javascript?

Below is my code:

```
     document.querySelector('modal-element').shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('custom-select-element').forEach(element => {
         const temp = element.cloneNode(true);
         element.parentElement.appendChild(temp);
         element.remove();
     });
```

However, the problem with this code is that `eventListener` registration is not done properly.

Therefore, when `element.render()` is executed and `element.remove()` is executed, one DOM is created by default and called with `element.render()`, unlike the expectation that only one is deleted. Both DOMs are removed.

I wonder how to delete and re-create the rendered DOM value with a web component.

Comment: Please use the [<>] button in the editor and include full code

Comment: "the problem with this code is that eventListener registration is not done properly"

I don't see where eventListener enters into this. Did you leave out part of the example?